# Нужно закончить цикл если ввели пустой ряд или нажали EOF

Tags: c

Цикл не заканчивается при *EOF*, но при пустом ряде заканчивается.
В чём может быть проблема? При *EOF* должен закончиться немедленно.
Пробовал писать и `if(a[0]==EOF) break;` но ничего не меняет.

```
char a[50], k[50], i = 0, b[50];
a[0] = 2;
int l;
while (a[0] != EOF && a[0] != 0) {
    gets(a);
    b[i] = check(a);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Не пишу на С, но EOF - это не символ, а состояние. Попробуйте, например, вместо EOF поставить пустую строку и посмотреть, не заработает ли.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте посмотрим на описание функции https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets

Там нигде не сказано, что она будет возвращать EOF  в первом символе. (Если что, EOF это число, равное -1). Там просто сказано, что эта функция возвратит NULL  в случае завершения/ошибки. Поэтому, этот цикл обычно переписывается вот так

```
while(gets(a) != NULL){
  b[i]=check(a);
  i++;
}
```

Да, особые ценители могут написать так

```
while(gets(a)){
  b[i]=check(a);
  i++;
}
```

(о том, что gets считается небезопасной и о том, что код сам чуточку странненький, я умолчу)

Comment: а вариант с `a[0]!=''` (пустая строка) не пройдёт в С? Или с `a[0]!=NULL`?

Comment: Нет конечно. Почитайте ещё раз документацию

Comment: Спасибо. Идея, которую я пытаюсь тут проверить, это нахождение общности в проблемах и выявление ошибок без детального изучения синтаксиса или выявление ошибок, быстрое нахождение ответов  в той или иной области без знания её (зачастую получается). Например, тут проверка на EOF, как на символ, сразу выглядела подозрительной.  Но, скорее всего, да, сработает это только на верхнем уровне.  С синтаксисом точно не стоит мне пытаться так действовать.

Comment: EOF работает, но не со всеми функциями. Так как это -1 и тип `int` (да да), то будет работать для тех функций, которые возвращают `int` (например, `getchar`, который для многих выглядит дико, так как все ждут, что там будет `char`).  "без детального изучения синтаксиса или выявление ошибок" - на начальном уровне это плохо работает. А вот напишите компилятор/интерпретатор - сразу чуйка будет:)